# How to extract a text from ng-herf with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, extract

There is a real state website with an infinite scroll down and I have tried to extract the companies' names and other details but I have a problem with writing the selectors need some insights for a new learner in scrapy.
HTML Snippet:
[image: inspect code image]

Answer (score 0):

After handling if *"more"* button is available in website.
So, the selector appears in most browsers you can copy selectors like this
[image: this an example]

based on the function you are using you copy "xpath" or something else for scrapping process,

If that's does not help please give the link to webpage and select what values you want to scrap.

Comment: Thank you but that didn't help extract the info that I want which is (company name. phone, email, address, and website. The site I want to scrape is this one https://aiwa.ae/category/real-estate and it also has an infinite scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to get the href from the tag and you don't know how to do it in scrapy.
you just need to add **::attr(ng-href)** this to the last of your CSS selectors.

```
link = response.css('your_selector::attr(ng-href)').get()
```

to make it easier for you your CSS selector should be

```
link = response.css('.companyNameSpecs a::attr(ng-href)').get()
```

but it looks like the href and ng-href is the same you can also do the same with it

```
link = response.css('your_selector::attr(href)').get()
```